# How to show a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is constant if it satisfies $f(x) + 3f(1-x) = 5$

Tags: functions

Let f be a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$. If for all real $x$,it satisfies
$$ f(x) + 3f(1-x) = 5$$ Then show that f is a constant function.

I tried it like this but not sure whether it is true or not.

$$ f(x) + 3f(1-x) = 5\tag 1$$

replace $x$ with $1-x$,
$$f(1-x) + 3f(x) = 5\tag 2$$

Then solving (1) and (2) we get $f(x) = \frac{5}{4}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Hence $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: $x=1-x$ only when $x=\frac12$

Comment: He worded it weirdly, he just replaced $x$ with $1-x$ which is certainly allowed @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @NoelLundström but there are better ways to word it without making that notational error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof works, but don’t write $x=1-x.$ That is only true if $x=\frac12.$

Instead, write:

> Let $y=1-x.$ Then:$$f(y)+3f(1-y)=f(1-x)+3f(x)=5.$$

and then finish the proof as you’ve done.

I realize that is what you really meant.

You could alternatively say, informally “substitute  $1-x$ for $x.$” But don’t use the equal sign ($=$).

Some people might accept:

> Letting $x:=1-x,\dots$

But that is not normally used.

Comment: It works over any set of numbers, even in quaternions. Any ring where $$3u+v=5\\u+3v=5$$ has only one solution. So, It does not work in a ring with characteristic $2.$ @Cretin2

Comment: Then were it possible to do a mapping from $\mathbb{F}_{2^p}$ to $[0;1]$ via binary coding, and then to $\mathbb{R}$ via a tan for example. Then since the function is not asked to be continuous this could be a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried $f(z)=A\cos(az-b)^2$, then $f(z)+3f(1-z)=A(g\cos(az)^2+h\sin(az)^2+k\sin(2az))$, where g,h,k are expressions in a,b. The equation implies $g=h$ and $k=0$ with the 2 unknowns a,b. Apparently there are complex solutions $b=\arcsin(\sqrt{\frac{3\pm i\sqrt{15}}{6}})$ and $a=\arcsin(\sqrt{\frac{4-2\sin(b)^2}{6}})+b$.
However a shall vanish to be coherent with the other solution, I'll have to check if I madea mistake.